# Jquery mobile + Phonegap + Eclipse, Cannot call javascript function for inner page other than index page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have two page (index.html and second.html) build with JQM and Phonegap, I wonder why all js function must be defined on index.html although I want to use it on second.html,

my script as below (second.html):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Loan Calculator</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/override.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function test(){alert("hello agent!");}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="agents">

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div class="ui-title">Agents</div>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <a href="#" onclick="test();">test</a>
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <p></p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Eclipse when I try click to trigger the function, it shown message like:

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 1 : Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

that is definitely cannot find the function on second.html page.

the js function test() doesn't work unless I put it in index.html.

I don't want all my mobile page loaded heavy in one page.

Your advise is much appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are browsing a mobile site that uses `jQuery Mobile`, any scripts included in the
`head` element will be read only on the page that you start from.
 So you start on the `index.html`
page and then the scripts that are in the head element of that page will be run.
 If you use
a button or a navigation bar to move to another page, the scripts in the head element on
those pages will be ignored because only the title element and the div element that
contains the `data-role="page"` attribute will be parsed and brought into the DOM.
This happens because of `jqm` inbuilt behavior of bringing the page using `Ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build *good* applications for PhoneGap (and ones that have a chance to be accepted in the AppStore especially) you need to avoid having multiple pages anyway, this will only cause you headache. Look into a good JS templating solution such as handlebars.js http://handlebarsjs.com/ and have a look at cconraets excellent phonegap tutorial http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/

Having page reloads in an app defeats the entire purpose really and JQuery Mobile is a beast, and all but nice to underperforming mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while when this question was asked.
But, I've got an answer.
Inside second.html put `<script src="Paging.js"></script>` where Paging.js would be the file where you write function (which you can call in onClick event) that will set window.location.href = "http:\...\index.html" and redirect you to index.html.
But be advised, it's not jQuery Mobile AJAX call and it will refresh (download js files from index.html, set elements, ...) the page once again.

Paging.js example:

```
function GotoIndex()
{
  window.location.href = "http:\\...\index.html";
}
```

second.html example:
...

```
<a href="#" id="lnkSubmitChanges" onclick="GotoIndex()">Submit</a>
```

...

If you ask yourself, but how can I get/set a variable for window.location.href, you could use localStorage.setItem('PreviousURL', window.location.href) in index.html and read it as localStorage.getItem('PreviousURL') in second.html.
Then the Paging.js would be:

```
function GotoIndex()
{
  window.location.href = localStorage.getItem('PreviousURL');
}
```